# is it ok to inject content view using dagger2

Tags: android, dagger-2, android-databinding

I'm using **data binding** in my android project, also i'm using **dagger 2** for **DI**.

basically for setting content view with data binding i need to do something like this :

```
LayoutClass layoutClass = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(Activity, Layout);
```

I'm providing that `layoutClass` in dagger **module** and injecting it to my activity. the question is, is this a good practice ?

Comment: There are two primary reasons to use dagger in code: decoupling and testability. I see no reason for this because content view is tightly coupled with activity anyway and you don't need to mock it in your tests

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Technically you're defining a circle-reference with this. You're just not warned, because setting up the graph requires you to be pro-active about this.

The dependencies would look like `activity -> layout -> activity` while you provide the module with an activity explicitly. Additionally you're modifying the activity with `DataBindingUtil.setContentView()` and therefore provide a dependency to the activity, which actually is a property of the activity itself.

So, never provide any UI with Dagger. Especially not to an activity.